# Authorizer context in API GW response

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

There is a new feature in API GW called "Gateway Responses". However the $context.authorizer.property is coming as blank in case "Custom Authorizer" rejects the request with Deny effect. Any idea how authorizer.context property can be sent back to calling application in case custom authorizer lambda function denies it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm asking the same question on the AWS forums. https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=260656